# Samsung Ace 3 - S7270 - Wifi and recovery mode problem

Tags: wi-fi, recovery-mode, samsung, samsung-kies

My Samsung Ace 3 does not detect any Wifi networks, and it cannot connect to `Kies`.

- My wifi network is fine, and there are lots of wifi networks in the area, but my SGA3 does not detect any of them (my other phone does).
- Kies does not detect my phone. It does detect other phones but not this one (same USB cable, same usb port,..).
- I can access the android file system using windows explorer (phone + sd card).
- I tried to go to download mode (Volume Up, Home, power off): it just shows an Android logo with an open chest with a keyboard. It stays that way for few minutes and the it proceeds to normal booting. (I tried pressing few buttons but it didn't work)

[image]

- I went to Factory mode (Volume down, Home, power off): it had a bunch of tests I can run, when I ran the Wifi test it gives me a "blank" mac address:

[image]

- What can I do? Please advise.